# Given probability generating function (PGF) for $X$, find PGF for $Y=2x+1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

PGF for $X$ is given by $G_{X}(t)=t^2e^{t-1}$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Find PGF for $Y=2X+1$.

I started it doing this:

$G_Y(t)=\mathbb{E}t^{2X+1}=t\cdot\mathbb{E}t^{2X}=t\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^{2k}\mathbb{P}(X=2k) $

And here I am stuck.

I tried finding $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$ by calculating $\frac{G_{X}^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$ but I do not seem to find any pattern.

Is there an easy way of finding $G_Y(t)$?

Comment: Note that
$$\mathbb{E}[t^{2X}] = \mathbb{E}[(t^2)^X] = G_X(t^2) = \ldots.$$

Comment: Wow, thanks! I am so stupid...